# How do I go about tackling this $\int_{0}^{1}{x^n\over \ln{y}+\ln{x}}dx$?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

How do I integrate

> $$I=\int_{0}^{1}{x^n\over \ln{y}+\ln{x}}dx\tag1$$

Honestly I haven't got any idea where to start. Any hints please?

Let $\ln{x}=-u\rightarrow du=-xdx$

$x=0\rightarrow u=\infty$

$x=1\rightarrow u=0$

$$I=-\int_{\infty}^{0}{e^{-u(n+1)}\over \ln{y}+u}du\tag2$$

Comment: It is relate to another problem that is why ln(y)

Comment: Wait a minute - what is the range of $y$ again? If $y \in (0,1)$ then $\ln y < 0$, so your integral really is an incomplete gamma function

Comment: I though this question would have a nice closed form.

Comment: It depends on your definittion of 'nice closed form'. I think it does have one

Comment: Something I can understand and recognise. Like pi, e or ln2 simple constant involve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $$I=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{n}}{\log\left(xy\right)}dx\overset{xy=u}{=}\frac{1}{y^{n+1}}\int_{0}^{y}\frac{u^{n}}{\log\left(u\right)}du.
 $$ Now let us consider $$I\left(a\right)=\int_{0}^{y}\frac{u^{n+a}}{\log\left(u\right)}du
 $$ we note that $$I'\left(a\right)=\int_{0}^{y}u^{n+a}du=\frac{y^{n+a+1}}{n+a+1}
 $$ hence, recalling the definition of the [exponential integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExponentialIntegral.html), we have $$I\left(a\right)=\textrm{Ei}\left(\log\left(y^{n+a+1}\right)\right)
 $$ then $$I=I\left(0\right)=\frac{\textrm{Ei}\left(\log\left(y^{n+1}\right)\right)}{y^{n+1}}.$$

Comment: How did you get from $I(a)$ to $I^{'}(a)$?

Comment: $\frac{d}{da}u^a=\log(u)\cdot u^a$

Comment: No problem :)
Nice Answer @Marco